# With Polymer how can you bind a class to the host element

Tags: polymer

I know that you can bind properties of an element to a class attribute using the syntax below for elements within a custom element,

```
<div id="arrow" class$="{{propertyName}}"></div>
```

but is it possible to apply a binding to the host element itself?  I've tried what is shown below, and various other attempts but have failed!

```
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">

<dom-module id="my-element" class$="{{propertyName}}">
    <template>
        <style>
        </style>
    </template>
    <script>
        Polymer({
            is:'my-element'
        });
    </script>
</dom-module>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want to do is possible, by [reflecting property value to attribute](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/properties#attribute-reflection).

```
Polymer({
  properties: {
    someProp: {
      reflectToAttribute: true
    }
  }
});
```

See below how the `class` and `other` properties' value is set on the host node.

I'm not sure though that redefining built-in properties like `class` is wise. If you want to use reflected properties for styling, better go for attribute selectors like I did with `me-elem[other]`.

```js
Polymer({
  is: 'my-elem',
  properties: {
    class: {
      reflectToAttribute: true,
      value: 'red'
    },
    other: {
      type: Boolean,
      reflectToAttribute: true,
      value: true
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <base href="https://polygit.org/components/">
  <script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
  <link href="polymer/polymer.html" rel="import"/>
</head>

<body>
  <style>
    .red {
      color: red;
    }
    
    my-elem[other] {
      border: solid 1px black;
    }
  </style>
  
  <my-elem></my-elem>
  
  <dom-module id="my-elem">
    <template>
      Some text   
    </template>
  </dom-module>
</body>
</html>
```

Finally, be careful with `reflectToAttribute`, because with large value serialized in DOM you can see a decrease in performance.